# Posting Column name as Integer

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the having gameid, hometeamid, visitorteamid,winnerid all as int.

The query

```
Update game set winnerid=hometeamid where gameid=1;
```

works fine on the Mysql workbench.

I am trying to run the same from a prepared statement without success throwing the error

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: 'hometeamid' for column 'winnerId' at row 1
```

since  "hometeamid" is passed as a string.
the code is as follows

```
String query = "update `match` set winnerid= ? where  gameid=?";
Map<Integer, String> data = getMap();//gameid and either 'hometeamid' or 'awaytemid'
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    ps.setObject(1, entry.getValue());
    ps.setInt(2, entry.getKey());
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e, e);
} finally {
    closeQuietly(connection);
}
```

How can I run the update correctly from a PreparedStatement?

Any other improvements recomendations are highly appreciated.

Comment: `entry.getValue()` returns probably `"hometeamid"` (`string`) and it's not an integer.

Comment: Yes it does but I need it as an unquoted  string as it is a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to something like:

```
String query = "update `match` set winnerid = case when ? = 'hometeamid' then hometeamid else visitorteamid end where  gameid=?"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a column name as a parameter in a prepared statement. You can only pass values.

If you really need this column name to be dynamic, then you'll have to use String concatenation to build this part of the query.

Comment: ION am using your guava retryer and loving it.